# Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info Ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got some issue for 2 days, it's getting on my nerve, if someone now how to fix this it will be very helpfull :

I've got a ionic 1 project, that I have to do some update, but nothing seems to work...
when i do ionic serve, and i look the console of the navigatori got :

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
```

and

```
ReferenceError: Connection is not defined
    at Object.isOnline
```

i'm stuck on the entry page and ng-src ng-click seems to not working.

I've look many post but nothing seems to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not all your angular scripts are the same version. .info was introduced recently, you might have angular files with different version.

Refer to related angular issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15786

Comment: yeah I saw this post and a try to put the same version of angular everywhere, but still have this issue

Comment: you mind posting more of that error a  screenshot or something of the first 5-10 lines. There should be more stack there.

Comment: I don't know if you want to see the package.json / bower.json / package-lock.json, I'm a bit lost with ionic1 I'm used to ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
    at angular-resource.js:445
    at angular-resource.js:858
```

angular-resource.js:445:

```
  angular.module('ngResource', ['ng']).
  info({ angularVersion: '1.6.4' }).
  provider('$resource', function ResourceProvider() {
    var PROTOCOL_AND_IPV6_REGEX = /^https?:\/\/\[[^\]]*][^/]*/;
```

at angular-resource.js:858:

```
})(window, window.angular);
```

Comment: all things based on research point to mis match version. Look at the version of the files in production, package.json wont help here, if the packages are not updated correctly. Attempt to force them all to be the same version instead of using ~ or ^ for version numbers.

Comment: I dont understand what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can't ionic serve, that app, but I can cordova build android, on the computer that has develops it , but not on my computer which I develops ionic 2 project.
I don't know if this is from my npm, node, cordova version or if is something completly diferent.